# The following JSrangeerroe was thrown building MobileScreen(dirty, dependencies: [.....] Invalid Argument maximum call stacksize exceede

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Getting the error: Invalid Arguments Maximum call stack size exceeded. Please let me know if you need any other details. This problem occurs after I added the provider package to my pubsec.yaml. and made some changes

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:luxurifyme/Models/car_attributes.dart';
import 'package:luxurifyme/Widgets/image_container.dart';
import 'package:luxurifyme/laptop_screen.dart';
import 'package:luxurifyme/mobile_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
runApp(
ChangeNotifierProvider(
  create: (context) => CarAttributes(),
  child: LuxurifyMe(),
),
);
}

class LuxurifyMe extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: Home(),
);
 }
 }

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.grey),
    elevation: 10.0,
    centerTitle: false,
    leadingWidth: 0,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    title: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 500
        ? Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
            child: Image.asset('images/luxury.png', fit: BoxFit.fitHeight),
          )
        : Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
            child: Image.asset('images/luxury.png', fit: BoxFit.cover),
          ),
  ),
  endDrawer: Drawer(
    elevation: 10.0,
  ),
  body: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 700
      ? LaptopScreen()
      : MobileScreen(),
  );
  }
  }
```

And the model Class is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CarAttributes extends ChangeNotifier {
String img;
String brandName;
String model;
String modelYear;
String fueltype;
String driven;
CarAttributes({
this.img,
this.brandName,
this.model,
this.modelYear,
this.fueltype,
this.driven,
});

  List<CarAttributes> cars = [
  CarAttributes(
  img: "images/l1.jpeg",
  brandName: "BMW",
  model: "Xl6",
  modelYear: "2018",
  fueltype: "Diesel",
  driven: "1182 Km",
  ),
  CarAttributes(
  img: "images/l2.jpeg",
  brandName: "Hyundai",
  model: "Creta",
  modelYear: "2018",
  fueltype: "Petrol",
  driven: "1194 Km",
  ),
  CarAttributes(
  img: "images/l3.jpeg",
  brandName: "Mercedez",
  model: "Gl6",
  modelYear: "2016",
  fueltype: "Diesel",
  driven: "4296 Km",
  ),
   CarAttributes(
  img: "images/l4.jpeg",
  brandName: "Mercedez",
  model: "Gl6",
  modelYear: "2017",
  fueltype: "Diesel",
  driven: "99212 Km",
   ),
   ];

 notifyListeners();
  }
```

And Final Screen Page is, Error is attached:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:luxurifyme/Models/car_attributes.dart';
import 'package:luxurifyme/Widgets/image_container.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class LaptopScreen extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 List<CarAttributes> newcars =
    Provider.of<CarAttributes>(context, listen: false).cars;

return GridView.builder(
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 1,
  ),
  itemCount: newcars.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ImageContainer(
      img: newcars[index].img,
      brandName: newcars[index].brandName,
      model: newcars[index].model,
      modelYear: newcars[index].brandName,
      fueltype: newcars[index].fueltype,
      driven: newcars[index].driven,
      );
      },
       );
       }
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrX7v.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am able to rectify this by separating the value initialization from the model class.